# Xpages Date Time

Tags: datetime, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm going loopy....

I want a date, in date format, for example

> 21/06/2017 17:23:04 GDT

I stamp this on a document, but I then want to display it on my xpage as:

> 21/06/2017 17:23

But I keep getting different results no matter what I do. I get the date from the onClick of a button using

```
var dt = new Date();
```

I then pass this into a function:

```
function AddObjectivesHistoryItem(doc, dt, action, username){

var ArrDocHistory:array = doc.getItemValueArray("History");

    if(ArrDocHistory.length < 1){
        // This should always return an object as it is created when an objectives document is first 
        // created but do this check to be safe and create an array if for some reason it doesnt exist
        ArrDocHistory = [dt+"|"+action+"|"+username];
    }else{
        // append new value to the array
        ArrDocHistory.push(dt+"|"+action+"|"+username);
    }
    doc.replaceItemValue("History",ArrDocHistory);
    doc.replaceItemValue("LastUpdatedByName",username);
    doc.replaceItemValue("LastUpdatedDate",dt); 
}
```

I've tried using toLocaleString() and all others it seems but it wont work.

For example, toLocaleString() displays as 13-Mar-2018 15:02:15 on my xpage. It's close to what I want except it uses hyphens instead of slashes, and also displays the seconds.

I've tried using custom date pattern on my date field properties with no luck and I'm certain I'm missing something super obvious!?

Any pointers on how to firstly get the date like 21/06/2017 17:23:04 GDT and store as a date and secondly to then display it as 21/06/2017 17:23, this can be a string if it needs to be.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your date value as String in SSJS with:

```
var dateTimeFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm");
var dateTimeString = dateTimeFormat.format(dt)));
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed, cheers Paul. FYI for anyone in a similar pickle, change the hh:mm to kk:mm if you want to show time in 24 hour format as I did

Comment: @Chris: good point - changed `hh` to `kk` in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store as text, `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` is best for converting a date server-side to a specific text format. It can also be used in a converter to manipulate to/from as well.

Comment: Hi Paul, my java isn't really that good. Are you saying I can't really achieve what I want from SSJS?